# How can I cover the hole left by removing a kitchen wall fan?

Tags: kitchens, fan

We had an old exhaust fan that vented out through the kitchen wall.  We removed it and drywalled over the hole, but are unsure how to cover the hole in the exterior siding.  Is there a cover for this or do we need to re-side the area?

Comment: What kind of siding?

Comment: People experienced with whatever siding you have are typically skilled in placing patches that are fairly unobtrusive, and often almost invisible.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps after insulation and sealing with foam, you could put a "dummy" vent cover over the now closed hole. Just seal it like it was real and you avoid the siding match problem. Fill the flapper with foam and it will be impervious to critters and weather.